# Pass data from controller to js and viceversa

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

This is my controller class:

```
public class TestController : Controller
    {
        log4net.ILog _logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(HomeController));
        //
        // GET: /Test/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<SelectListItem> testlist = new List<SelectListItem>();
            SelectListItem s = new SelectListItem();
            s.Value = "--Select One--";
            s.Text = "--Select One--";
            testlist.Add(s);
            ViewBag.Items = testlist;

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult PassToView()
        {
            List<SelectListItem> testlist = new List<SelectListItem>();
            SelectListItem s = new SelectListItem();
            s.Text = "data1";
            s.Value = "data1";
            testlist.Add(s);

            s = new SelectListItem();
            s.Text = "data2";
            s.Value = "data2";
            testlist.Add(s);

            s = new SelectListItem();
            s.Text = "data3";
            s.Value = "data3";
            testlist.Add(s);

            s = new SelectListItem();
            s.Text = "data4";
            s.Value = "data4";
            testlist.Add(s);

            s = new SelectListItem();
            s.Text = "data5";
            s.Value = "data5";
            testlist.Add(s);

            return Json(testlist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        public ActionResult PassToController(string SelectedValue)
        {
            _logger.Info("Selected value is :" + SelectedValue);
            return View();
        }

    }
```

This is my view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@Html.DropDownList("ddlItems", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Items, new { @id = "ddlItems", @class = "dropdownlist", onchange = "ddlItemChange();" }) 
<script  type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON("/Test/PassToView", function (data) {
            var selectList = $("#ddlItems");
            selectList.empty();
            $.each(data, function (index, optionData) {
                var option = $('<option>').text(optionData.Text).val(optionData.Value);
                selectList.append(option);
            });
            selectList.trigger("chosen:updated");
        });
    });

    function ddlItemChange() {
        var selectedvalue = $("select[name='ddlItems']").val();
        $.post("/Test/PassToController", { SelectedValue: selectedvalue });
        return false;
    }

</script>
```

The drop down list is not getting filled. Please see the image attached.
[image]

Could you please tell me where i'm doing wrong.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Press `F12` on chrome to open developer tools and see if there's any javascript errors? I tested your code on my computer, the dropdown is loaded. Maybe you haven't included `jquery` in a script tag?

Comment: If so, how to include jquery in script tag?

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint.. I added <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script> Now it is working

Comment: Now it is working fine while running through Visual Studio. But after published and hosted in IIS, then it is not working? Appreciate any hints to resolve?

Comment: Hope the server you hosted can access this file `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js`?

Comment: I have resolved the issue by replacing. 
$.getJSON("/Test/PassToView", function (data) {
with 
$.getJSON('@Url.Content(~/Test/PassToView)', function (data) {